# If no cards in discard pile, when playing swashbuckler but have 4 coffers, are you allowed to take the treasure chest?

Tags: dominion

When playing the swashbuckler, if my discard pile has no cards in it, but I have at least 4 coffer tokens, can I take the treasure chest? (not sure if that only applies to the taking an additional coffer or to everything following.)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a question be answered by 4 people at once more or less simultaneously before!

Comment: @StartPlayer we are just eager to help. And due to the Corona it is hard to get people together to play so we have some time to spare.

Comment: Oh I know I answered my self.  when you start typing there were no answers and by time I hit enter there were three already there.  I'm glad we all gave the same answer!

Comment: Yeah I also didn’t see a “new answer” notification. And generally with Dominion questions there isn’t quite as large a following!

Answer (score 3):

No; the “if your discard pile has any cards in it” applies to the rest of the text.

From the [official FAQ](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Swashbuckler):

> You cannot get the Treasure Chest unless your discard pile had at least one card.

Answer (score 2):

No. The card text is clear on the breakpoint.

> +3 cards

That's one line, and then the condition-colon-effect portion:

> If your discard pile has any cards in it: +1 Coffers, then if you have at least 4 Coffers tokens, take the Treasure Chest.

But see also the [FAQ](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Swashbuckler):

> First you draw 3 cards, then you check to see if your discard pile has any cards in it; if drawing those cards caused you to shuffle, your discard pile would be empty.
> If your discard pile has at least one card, you get +1 Coffers, and if you then have 4 or more tokens on your Coffers, you take the Treasure Chest.
> **You cannot get the Treasure Chest unless your discard pile had at least one card.**

Answer (score 2):

The [actions of the Swashbuckler](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Swashbuckler) are:

> 1. You draw 3 cards
> 2. You check to see if your discard pile has any cards in it; if drawing those cards caused you to shuffle, your discard pile would be
>    empty.
> 3. If your discard pile has at least one card, you get +1 Coffers, and if you then have 4 or more tokens on your Coffers, you take the
>    Treasure Chest.
>
> You cannot get the Treasure Chest unless your discard pile had at
> least one card.

You need to take the treasure chest the moment you get the fourth coffer. So it is not possible to get the treasure chest if you didn't get the coffer. So no you wouldn't get the treasure chest if the discard pile is empty because you will not get a Coffer.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Swashbuckler card]

Reading this it seems to me that would not.  That colon looks very much like everything that follows it is reliant on not having an empty discard pile.  This is also backed up by the [Dominion Strategy wiki](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Swashbuckler) which says the same in section labeled official FAQ.